# GWT project with back end

Tags: gwt, jakarta-ee, backend

UPDATE: My apologies for the ambiguity of the word back end. The definiton used for this question is:

"In Web content management systems the terms front end and back end may refer to the end-user facing views of the CMS and the administrative views respectively."

We want to create an app which got a backend administration interface. I've seen plenty of products using a backend but I got no idea of how they work or are desgined.

Among my biggest doubts are:

- Whats the common approach to pass changes (make the client aware of changes) from the admin to the client view?
- Should I split the apps in 2 and give each a different port or just everything together?
- Would question number 2 approach would affect number 1?

Additional details are:

Is a web project using GWT with JAVA. It will be deployed on a Jboss server.

About the ports: Since everything is web, what I was wondering is if I should split the app in 2 and have the server listening to 2 ports (via proxy, whatever) and redirect accordingly, or allow access to administration backend through the front end.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick trick for evaluating technologies and designs to help you make comparisons about the Right Way (for you) to get your job done:  Write a number-guessing game where the computer picks a number and tells you if your guess is too high or too low.  The game is simple enough that it's not a distraction from thinking about the technology that you're evaluating, but it requires that you gain a base understanding of how UI and control flow work in the particular toolchain.  It also allows you to formulate much more specific questions than the one above, which is essentially an opinion poll.

Comment: I guess my initial question was somehow ambiguous. I'm not evaluating technologies. I want to know the programmer approach to make backends for web apps, specifically (or not) with GWT

Answer (score 0):

Your question 2 LARGELY depends on which technique you are using. If you are using the j2ee and subsidary technology stacks, you might not need to distinguish between ports at all because everything is web. This would affect your point #1 because whole webcommunications is at this time rather pull than push - your client asks the server: "Are there news?"

As your question is tagged "web-development" I assume that "web" is your design choice for now? 
That could be python, php, java (with GWT, JSF, etc)

You've got a huge toolset to pick of, I think you need to make a choice, because otherwise you'll get lost...

Comment: With http://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/ you can also push messages from server to client.

Comment: @Ethan Leroy ok, thats the kind of technical answer I'm looking, could you elaborate more?